# In what situations would a target be denied a Dex bonus to AC?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, rogue, sneak-attack, armor-class

I have an encounter coming up where my PCs will face a high level rogue. Naturally, I'd like to use his sneak attack ability, but I've never played a rogue before so I'm light on experience.

From the rules, I see that sneak attack damage is applied when:

1. The rogue's target would be denied a Dexterity bonus to AC (whether the target actually has a Dexterity bonus or not)
2. The rogue flanks her target.

For #1, is there a list of non-magical situations/conditions where a target would be denied a Dex bonus to AC? Is there a page in the PHB that includes this, that I'm just not finding?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I did some more research online and some situations/conditions, where a target is denied its dex bonus to AC, are:

1. Blinded
2. Cowering
3. Flat-Footed (target hasn't yet acted in combat)
4. Attacker is Invisible
5. Stunned
6. Paralyzed
7. Helpless
8. Pinned via Grapple
9. Acrobatics to Cross Narrow Surfaces/Uneven Ground
10. Climbing
11. Running
12. Squeezing
13. Social situations preventing awareness of the attack
14. Successfully Feinted against
15. Overloaded from encumbrance
16. ["off balance" in the water](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/environment/wilderness/terrain/aquatic-terrain#TOC-Underwater-Combat)

See also the [Combat Modifiers table](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/combat.html#combat-modifiers).

Note that flanking a target allows a rogue to use Sneak Attack and gives a +2 attack bonus, but does not actually deny a target's dex bonus to AC.

Are the others I've missed?

Comment: RAI include any time the target is unaware of the attacker, such as after Stealth: http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2pt9j&page=2?Stealth-Errata#64

Comment: your linked combat modifiers table says that the grappled defender loses his dex bonus to AC. is this an inconsistency or is that table correct?

Answer (score 13):

[Combat Modifiers](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/combat.html#combat-modifiers) in the Combat chapter outlines the main conditions that deny Dexterity bonus to AC:

- Attacker is invisible (attacker gains +2 to attack)
- Target is blinded (target suffers -2 to AC)
- Target is cowering, such as from a *[fear](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/fear.html#_fear)* spell (-2 to AC)
- Target is flat-footed because he has not taken his turn yet in this combat
- **D&D 3.5 only, not Pathfinder**: Target is grappling someone other than the attacker
- Target is helpless, e.g.: unconscious, sleeping, paralyzed, bound (-4 to AC against melee, and Dex modifier counts as -5)
- Target is pinned (-4 to AC against melee)
- Target is stunned (-2 to AC)

Other circumstances in which a creature loses its Dexterity bonus to AC:

- [Running](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/combat.html#_run), unless you have the Run feat
- [Squeezing](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/combat.html#_squeezing) through a gap less than half your space's width
- Off-balance when [fighting underwater](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/environment.html#_underwater-combat), usually due to a failed Swim check
- Using [Acrobatics](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/skills/acrobatics.html#_acrobatics) to cross narrow surfaces or uneven ground
- [Climbing](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/skills/climb.html#_climb)
- Attacker makes a successful [feint](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/skills/bluff.html#_feint)
- Attacker is using certain feats, such as [Disengaging Shot](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/ultimateCombatFeats.html#_disengaging-shot) or [False Opening](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/ultimateCombatFeats.html#_false-opening)
- Attacker has certain class abilities, such as the Magus ability [prescient attack](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/classArchetypes/magus.html#_prescient-attack)

You don't lose Dexterity to AC just for being prone or casting a spell. In D&D 3.5, your target is denied Dexterity to AC if grappled by someone other than yourself, but this no longer occurs in Pathfinder unless the target is also pinned.