# Choosing a weapon for a low STR sorcerer in Pathfinder

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, sorcerer

I'm making a Half-Orc Red Draconic Sorcerer, which will begin life at level 5 to join an existing campaign. Based on my rolls I'll probably have 8 STR and 16 DEX.

So I'm using my starting gold to go shopping, and I'm having a hard time figuring out what to wield. Melee weapons and bows both seem to take STR to be able to hit. And even if I took Weapon Finesse or something, I would still get a penalty to damage.

I don't want to rely on weapons, but spell casting are limited, and I don't want to be useless when I'm out. Some magic affixes seem neat, but I have 10,500 total gold to spend and can't spent more than half on one single item, which puts most of those out of reach.

So what should I be clutching in my hands?

Comment: What race is this Sorc?

Comment: Half-orc. Sorry I left that out.

Comment: [Related.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/37409/8610) (Although that question's geared toward lower-level characters and wizards, it's so you know that similar concerns have been raised.)

Comment: [Also related](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/56869/15469) (Although it's 3.5, so not necessarily all that useful).

Comment: Pro tip: In addition to whatever you choose, buy a [Spiked Gauntlet](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/gauntlet-spiked) unless you have other means of always threatening at 5ft. range. This is for the purpose of using you as a flanking buddy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ranged weapons that are not thrown (like bows, crossbows) [use DEX to hit](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Attack-Bonus), so a shortbow or any crossbow is a valid option and you will not take any Strength penalties using these weapons.

Dipping just one level into Swashbuckler (assuming you're allowed Hybrid Classes) nets you the [Swashbuckler Finesse](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/swashbuckler#TOC-Swashbuckler-Finesse-Ex-) class feature, which gives you Weapon Finesse as a bonus feat and theoretically helps your CHA-based sorcerer learn combat feats quicker.

If you want to get really involved in melee, you can then invest in [Weapon Focus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/weapon-focus-combat---final) and [Slashing Grace](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/slashing-grace-combat) get your Dex to damage (but I feel that might be a bit far off from your goal).

Comment: I'd suggest noting that while a shortbow doesn't have STR-related penalties to hit, with an 8 STR it will have a -1 to damage.  Light crossbow is probably therefore indicated for this character, unless they go the Finesse + Slashing Grace route.