# Does grapple condition make you flatfooted?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, grapple

When you are grappled (not pinned or tied up) are you considered flatfooted to either the thing grappling you or things not involved in the grapple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  [The grappled condition](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions/#TOC-Grappled) describes what effects apply to someone grappled - no more, no less.  They are not [flat-footed](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions/#TOC-Flat-Footed), nor have they lost their Dexterity mod to AC (a condition frequently confused with [flat-footed](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions/#TOC-Flat-Footed)).

Comment: There goes the idea of the grappling rogue I had

Comment: If that's your goal perhaps you should review http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/27215/in-what-situations-would-a-target-be-denied-a-dex-bonus-to-ac.